# Reading Tweets via Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, twitter

So I'm following this tutorial http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/10/12/android-dev-tutorial-now-available-on-the-gvsu-itunes-u-portal/ and have had no problems what so ever until now.

On Module 3, the app downloads data from twitter and displays them in a list view. I followed the lecture video and understand everything. However, once I tried it on my own I ran into issues. I even copy and pasted the lecture source code and still can't get it to work.

What I'm wondering, is it my mistake? or does it have to do with some obsolete code, as the tutorial is more than a few years old?

Here's my 2 java classes:
http://pastebin.com/g27HrgN3
http://pastebin.com/d7kD0gr4

The app never lists any twitter data like it's supposed to. Here's the app output
[image]

here's what I get as output on my environment
[image]
[image]

As you can tell, I'm new to android programming, a point in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}`

That explains.

Comment: Where do you see that error message? I can't find it

Comment: @ComputerDope I simply visited the URL your TWITTER_SEARCH constant defines in TwitterHelper in my browser, simply passing it a random argument (or none at all).

Comment: Ah ok, i didn't even think of that. Thank you very much for the quick and helpful explanation